# internet surfing and isp

Tags: anonymity, unlinkability, internet-service-provider

When you browse the web you first have to connect to the isp servers or something like that. Is there a way of surfing the net without passing into them? So he wouldn't for example be able to see that I use tor.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't a way to avoid going through your ISP. To avoid being detected as a Tor user, you need to use a [pluggable transport](https://www.torproject.org/docs/pluggable-transports.html.en). Unfortunately, there's no guarantee that your ISP won't learn you're a Tor user even when you use one, tho.